# Why does the 'stackalloc' keyword not work with properties?

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, properties, unsafe

I was writing some unsafe code recently in C# and noticed this produces a syntax error:

```
public unsafe class UnsafeByteStream
{
    public UnsafeByteStream(int capacity)
    {
        this.Buffer = stackalloc byte[capacity];
    }

    public byte* Buffer { get; }
}
```

The result of this is: `"Invalid expression term 'stackalloc' / ; expected / } expected"`. However, when I assign this first to a local field, like so:

```
public UnsafeByteStream(int capacity)
{
    byte* buffer = stackalloc byte[capacity];
    this.Buffer = buffer;
}
```

Then there is no syntax error produced.

Is there a reason for this, or is something up with the compiler? I understand that pointer-type properties are not all that common, but I still don't understand why this is a *syntax* error as opposed to a *semantic* one, assuming something's wrong with the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stackalloc` *must* be part of the local variable declaration, as [discussed in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx9s2sy4.aspx).

> The [stackalloc] keyword is **valid only in local variable *initializers***. The following code causes compiler errors.
>
> ```
> int* block;
> // The following assignment statement causes compiler errors. You
> // can use stackalloc only when declaring and initializing a local 
> // variable.
> block = stackalloc int[100];
> ```

As such it truly is a syntax error; and rejects the `obj.Property = stackalloc ..` form.

(The later assignment to a property is an - uncaught - semantic error.)

Comment: Oh, *that's* the reason. I was suspecting it had something to do with `UnsafeByteStream` being allocated on the heap since it's a class, and therefore it couldn't hold a `stackalloc'd` byte array... sometimes when you think too far in, you don't see what's right in front of you.

Comment: @JamesKo It is an interesting question; the (cryptic) syntax error caught me off guard.