# Why does stackalloc have to be used as a variable initializer?

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, unsafe, stackalloc

I'm writing some unsafe code in C# (follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32343050/18192)) and I'm wondering, why exactly does the [`stackalloc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx9s2sy4.aspx) keyword have to be used as a variable initializer? e.g. This will produce a syntax error:

```
public unsafe class UnsafeStream
{
    byte* buffer;

    public UnsafeStream(int capacity)
    {
        this.buffer = stackalloc byte[capacity]; // "Invalid expression term 'stackalloc' / ; expected / } expected"
    }
}
```

But re-assigning the results from a local temporary will not:

```
public UnsafeStream(int capacity)
{
    byte* buffer = stackalloc byte[capacity];
    this.buffer = buffer;
}
```

Why isn't the first version allowed, and what evil things will happen if I attempt the second version?

Comment: Why do you want to assign data on the stack to a member?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Basically, I'm looking to make a faster version of `MemoryStream` (like `UnmanagedMemoryStream`, except portable) that uses pointers and a length instead of arrays.

Comment: The field lives longer than the lifetime of the stack memory. The local does not. If you do not understand how this works then do not use unsafe code until you do. Unsafe code is for experts who thoroughly understand memory management.

Comment: In addition to the problems mentioned by others, you could fill up your stack real quick when doing this.

Comment: With such a memory stream idea, one would want to be careful to measure the impact of just about every little thing, because it's easy to do something that looks like it will speed things and actually makes it slower. Or speeds it in isolation, but then slows it in practice. Stackalloc can very often slow things up quite a bit, even if you throw some other threads putting pressure on the heap into the tests, to make the impact of `fixed` worse.

Comment: @vesan @JonHanna So it looks like `fixed` is the way to go after all, then.

Comment: When you're working with buffers through pointers, you can **sometimes** find that small buffers used for within a method benefit from `stackalloc`. If you're using managed memory though, you're likely to find that whether fixed or stack, they can cost more than they pay, especially when there is pressure on the heap that simpler profiling might not catch, so try having another thread churn a bit in some of your speed comparison tests, to be sure you aren't lead down an unfruitful route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your stack is looking something very roughly like this:

```
[stuff from earlier calls][stuff about where this came from][this][capacity]
                                                                   ^You are here
```

Then you do `stackalloc` and this adds two things to the stack, the pointer and the array pointed to:

```
[stuff from earlier calls][stuff about where this came from][this][capacity][buffer][array pointed to by buffer]
                                                                                            ^You are here
```

And then when you return the stuff most recently put on the stack, the locals of the current function, its return address, and the `stackalloc`ed buffer are all simply ignored (which is one of the advantages of `stackalloc`, ignoring stuff is fast and easy):

```
[stuff from earlier calls][stuff about where this came from][this][capacity][buffer][array pointed to by buffer]
                       ^You are here
```

It can be overwritten by the next method call:

```
[stuff from earlier calls][stuff about where this came from][this][new local1][new local2]o by buffer]
                                                                                 ^You are here
```

What you are proposing, is that a private field, which is to say a part of an object on the heap (a different piece of memory, managed differently) hold a pointer to the buffer that has been half-overwritten by completely different data, of different types.

Immediately consequences would be:

1. Attempts to use `buffer` are now fraught because half of it is overwritten by item, most of which aren't even bytes.
2. Attempts to use any local is now fraught, because future changes to `buffer` can overwrite them with random bytes in random places.

And that's just considering the single thread involved here, never mind other threads with separate stacks perhaps being able to access that field.

It's also just not very useful. You can coerce a field to hold an address to somewhere on a stack with enough effort, but there isn't that much good one can do with it.

Comment: Makes sense, I'll accept your answer. Any reason in particular though why reassignments to *locals*, e.g. `byte* buffer; buffer = stackalloc byte[123];` are prohibited as well?

Comment: @JamesKo I'm guessing because `byte* buffer;` is doing the allocation? Also, it would allow you to allocate to the heap rather than the stack conditionally, which, I'm sure would break some things.

Comment: @Rob Not necessarily true, you can set `byte* buffer = null` and it won't make one (except of course for the pointer variable itself).

Comment: You can reassign to another variable, or reassign `buffer` after the `stackalloc`. It's a convenience though that (like `fixed`) you have to stick with one variable initialised to the address of that block of memory, since that block of memory is going to be sectioned off for the lifetime of the method, and you wouldn't want code that behaves like it isn't.